# How can I format an array of structures for a printed report in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a program that accepts input from textboxes and puts that input into an array of structures. The structures include a string variable for a name, an array of 5 doubles, and finally a double that holds the average of the values in the previous array. I am trying to be able to send the whole array of structures to a printable report, but I am having a great deal of difficulty in formatting such a volume of data for the printer. To better explain my difficulties, here is what I have written so far:

```
'Print the report header
e.Graphics.DrawString("Class Report",
                      New Font("Courier New", 12, FontStyle.Bold),
                      Brushes.Black,
                      150,
                      10)

e.Graphics.DrawString("Date and Time: " & Now.ToString(),
                      New Font("Courier New", 12, FontStyle.Bold),
                      Brushes.Black,
                      10,
                      38)

'Prints the column headers
e.Graphics.DrawString(String.Format("{0, 20} {1, 20} {2, 20}",
                                    "Name",
                                    "Test Scores",
                                    "Average"),
                      New Font("Courier New", 12, FontStyle.Bold),
                      Brushes.Black,
                      10,
                      66)

'prints the data
For intCount = 0 To 5
    e.Graphics.DrawString(String.Format("{0, 20} {1, 5} {2, 5} {3, 5} {4, 5} {5, 5} {6, 5} {7, 20}",
                                        ClassScores(intCount).strName,
                                        ClassScores(intCount).dblTestScores(0),
                                        ClassScores(intCount).dblTestScores(1),
                                        ClassScores(intCount).dblTestScores(2),
                                        ClassScores(intCount).dblTestScores(3),
                                        ClassScores(intCount).dblTestScores(4),
                                        ClassScores(intCount).dblTestAvg),
                          New Font("Courier New", 12, FontStyle.Regular),
                          Brushes.Black,
                          150,
                          165)
Next
```

Now as it stands this code throws a system.format exception. This is incredibly confusing to me, as previously Im fairly certain I had this exact code before attempting to make some changes to how what exactly is being printed (i.e. converting the structures to parallel string arrays), however I abandoned that attempt and tried to get back to the previous version of the code, unsuccessfully apparently.

That being said, when I actually had the code working the printed document had a number of problems. For instance the header lines were not centered but rather hanging off to the top right of the document. Second when the actual data was printed all of the data was printed on one line, the names in one column, and all the numbers in another, all printed on top of each other. To specifically enumerate what I am seeking assistance with:

1. How do I clear up the system.format exception with this code?
2. When the loop loops how do I ensure that the new data is fit onto a new line in the printed document?
3. I could use some help in understanding the format string numbers, especially regarding the header and how I am meant to determine how wide my columns should be.

Many thanks in advance. This program has a lot of moving parts so if you want more context on the type of data I am working with let me know, as I do not know how helpful the information I have given is

Comment: 1. What's the error message?

Comment: 2. You're specifying an X and a Y coordinate for where to draw the `String`. If you want each line to be further down the page then the Y coordinate needs to increase.

Comment: 3. You're specifying the width and alignment of each column. A positive width means right-aligned and a negative width means left-aligned. Given that you have five columns of width 5 for the scores, your header for those columns needs to be 5x5+4=29 while you have only specified 20.

Comment: Don't keep creating `Font` objects over and over.  They are all the same so just create one and reuse it. Also, you should be disposing that one `Font` when you're done with it. To that end, create it with a `Using` statement then it will be implicitly disposed at the end of the block.

Comment: With regards to increasing the Y coordinate at which you draw a record, as you're in a `For` loop, the obvious thing to do is to multiply the loop counter by the line height and add that to your base Y value.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that the format specifier you're passing to that second `String.Format` call expects eight values (indexes 0 to 7) while you are only passing seven (1 x name, 5 x score, 1 x average).  Your format specifier should be:

> {0, 20} {1, 5} {2, 5} {3, 5} {4, 5} {5, 5} {6, 20}

rather than

> {0, 20} {1, 5} {2, 5} {3, 5} {4, 5} {5, 5} {6, 5} {7, 20}

Comment: Apologies for the wait. 1. The exception is a System.Format Exception, it reads "Index(zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list"

Comment: This answer fixed the exception, however All of the data is still falling on one line, and the first two headers are still missalligned